# Android: NullPointerException on SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView()

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor, android-filter

I am experiencing some crashes when using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
It's only happening with users having Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4, but it's very nasty as it interests 1% of all my users, which is not little.

it was [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=tools_r21) on 19th June 2012, with comment:
"*Fix crash when SimpleCursorAdapter changes cursor from null when the spinner's drop-down view is shown.*" ([this is the diff](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/diff?spec=svn.platform--frameworks--base.40f2f751ac7cebc455b44da23b9589cca5ae2e25&repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=tools_r21&r=87ab6962e44914fdee767c5be6b316228d2b7889&format=side&path=/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java&old_path=/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java&old=f76a50ce8fdc6aea22cabc77b2977a1a15a79630))

How can I avoid crashes for those users who still have Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 ?

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
>          at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
>          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2424)
>          at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1168)
>          at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1251)
>          at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1095)
>          at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524)
>          at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$PopupDataSetObserver.onChanged(ListPopupWindow.java:1219)
>          at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:35)
>          at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
>          at android.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:341)
>          at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:347)
>          at android.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:309)
>          at android.widget.CursorFilter.publishResults(CursorFilter.java:67)
>          at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: You could try switching to [the `SimpleCursorAdapter` copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) that is in `support-v4` and `support-v13`, in hopes that incorporates this fix.

Comment: `How can I avoid crashes`. You  could check for null and not continue. Display a Toast.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter isn't hardware dependent.  If it has a bug that's been fixed and you need the fix, there's no reason you can't take a fixed version from AOSP, rename it, and use the renamed version.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tried to use android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter, but I get another NullPointerException "Attempt to read from null array" on line 135. It doesn't seem to present on v13.

Comment: @greenapps, where should I check for null? the NPE is happening in the Android framework code

Comment: Well, `support-v13` has a superset of the classes that are in `support-v4`, so it should be there. Note that it will still have `v4` in the package name. And, since it should be the same class that is in `support-v4`, if you are having problems with the `support-v4` one, `support-v13` is unlikely to help.

Comment: Well than I have said nothing. Sorry.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I am actually going to try what you suggest. The fixed class in Android framework is actually different from the class in support-v4. Let's see if it fixes, and above all, it doesn't introduce other problems in earlier devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I realized the support-v4 version of SimpleCursorAdapter is actually older than the one in Android 4.0.3. I just filed a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162255&thanks=162255&ts=1427561257

Comment: "I realized the support-v4 version of SimpleCursorAdapter is actually older than the one in Android 4.0.3" -- oh, yuck. That's kinda the point behind having the copy in the Android Support package, so it is up-to-date relative to what might be in the firmware. Sorry to have lead you on a wild goose chase there.

Comment: @CommonsWare, the latest bug fixes are not related to firmware. So, I don't see why they shouldn't be included in the support class.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I can confirm you that your solution perfectly solved the problem!!!!!! thank you!!!!! if you want to write an official answer to this question, I will confirm it as the solution